# How to convert an IQueryable<T> to an Array[T] in ASP.NET Core?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

```
public IActionResult ResetPassword(string userName)
{
    Account[] users = userManager.Users.ToArray() ;
    Account user = new Account();

    foreach (Account userNumber in users)
    {
        if (userNumber.UserName == userName)
        {
            user = userNumber;
        }
    }
}
```

For some reason, the `Account` user is returning blank, despite `userName` containing a value within the `Users`.

I've tried switching from the `ToList()` method to the `ToArray()` method, and it still returns nothing. Any help or redirections would be much appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.
Please take the [tour] to learn how Stack Overflow works and read [ask] on how to improve the quality of your question.
Then [edit] your question to include your source code as a working [mcve], which can be compiled and tested by others.

Comment: This is a very convoluted (and inefficient) way of just calling `FirstOrDefault()` on `Users`. Also, that code doesn't compile as is (no `return` statement), so clearly it's not your actual code.

Answer (score 0):

```
class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            IQueryable<Product> productsQueryable = new Product[] {
                new Product {Id = 0, Name = "Tapash"},
                new Product {Id = 1, Name = "Tapash1"},
                new Product {Id = 2, Name = "Tapash2"}
            }.AsQueryable();

            //basic c# feature
            var basicMethods = productsQueryable.ToArray();

            //custom functions
            Product[] products = InitializeArray<Product>(productsQueryable);
            Console.WriteLine(products);
        }
        public static T[] InitializeArray<T>(IQueryable<T> arg) where T : new()
        {
            T[] array = new T[arg.Count()];
            for (int i = 0; i < arg.Count(); ++i)
            {
                array[i] = arg.ElementAt(i);
            }
            return array;
        }
    }
```

Comment: How does that answer the question...? Also, that `InitializeArray` method is _incredibly_ inefficient, what with the `Count()` and all the `ElementAt` calls, each of which will lead to one call to the database.